# How to properly fit a non-linear equation to a set of datapoints?

Tags: math, curve-fitting, equation, curve

I have a curve of net longwave radiation (QL) data, which are calculated as follows:

```
QL = a*Ta^4 - b*Ts^4
where a and b are constants, Ta is the air temperature and Ts is the surface temperature
```

If I plot a curve of QL versus Ta-Ts, what type of equation should I use to fit the data as follows y = f(x) where x = (Ta-Ts)?

Thanks

```
-20.5   -176.683672
-19.5   -171.0655836
-18.5   -165.8706233
-17.5   -158.9990897
-16.5   -154.2715535
-15.5   -147.5376901
-14.5   -141.2410818
-13.5   -135.3387669
-12.5   -129.3971791
-11.5   -122.0777208
-10.5   -117.475907
-9.5    -111.107148
-8.5    -104.5999237
-7.5    -99.82769298
-6.5    -93.43215832
-5.5    -87.6278432
-4.5    -81.85415752
-3.5    -76.5997892
-2.5    -70.26308516
-1.5    -65.49437303
-0.5    -60.78052134
0.5 -56.32077454
1.5 -51.74037492
2.5 -47.30542394
3.5 -42.92298839
4.5 -38.13260904
5.5 -34.22676827
6.5 -30.49502686
7.5 -26.89383663
8.5 -22.259631
```

[image]

The complete data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e3gNCKQesrGe9ESrEIUcQw3umERzNRt0/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115727378140347660572&rtpof=true&sd=true:

```
TS = surface temperature (degrees Celsius);
TA = air temperature (degrees Celsius);
Lin = longwave in (0.8 * 5.67E-8 * (TA+273.15)^4) (W m-2);
Lout = longwave out (0.97 * 5.67E-8 * (TS+273.15)^4) (W m-2);
QL = Lin - Lout (W m-2);
```

Comment: Since it looks so close to a straight line, you could try to fit it by a piecewise linear function, with a small (maybe 2 or 3) number of pieces. See also [Decision tree with final decision being a linear regression?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/65585/decision-tree-with-final-decision-being-a-linear-regression)

Comment: Do you know the value of Ta ? If not do you know the value of Ts ?

Comment: Is Ta constant and Ts variable ? Or is Ta variable and Ts constant ? Or what else ? There is someting missing in the present wording of the question. Without more information the problem is undetermined.

Comment: Ta and Ts are both variable!

Comment: Fourth order polynomial looks like it'd be sufficient.

Comment: **Always use dimensionless quantiles when curve fitting non-linear data.**  Otherwise you end up with things quantities raised to fractional powers, like `m^0.52434544` which is non-sensical. Specifically in your case the fit coefficients will not be independent of the choice of `Ta` and `Ts`.

Comment: The model suggests a 4-th order polynomial would suffice.

Comment: If the model is : 
QL = a * (TA+273.15)^4 - b * (TS+273.15)^4 
the coefficients a and b can be computed from your data thanks to a simple linear regression. One found that the computed values of a and b are very far from the expected values a=0.8 * 5.67E-8 and b=0.97 * 5.67E-8 . This suggests that there is something missing in the modelisation and as a consequence something wrong in the above function.

Comment: Possibly Lout is underestimated. Lout might be not from radiation only. No convective and/or conductive losses  taken into account in the model ?

Answer (score 1):

The notation QL=y=f(x) is falacious because QL doesn't depends on one variable only, but depends two independant variables Ta and Ts.

So, one have to write : y=F(Ta,Ts) or equivalently y=g(x,Ta) or equivalently y=h(x,Ts) with x=Ta-Ts and the functions F or g or h.

Any one of those functions can be determined thanks to nonlinear regression if we have data on the form of a table of three columns (not only two columns) for example :

(Ta,Ts,y) to find the function F(Ta,Ts)

or (x,Ta,y) to find the function g(x,Ta)

or (x,Ts,y) to find the function h(x,Ts)

In fact one cannot definitively answer to your question in which something is missing : Either measurements of another parameter or another relationship between the parameters in addition to the relationship x=Ta-Ts.

Of course one can compute (for example) the coefficients A,B,C,... for a polynomial regression of the kind f(x)=A+Bx+Cx^2+... and get a very good fitting :

[image]

The coefficients A,B,C are purely mathematical without physical signifiance. The coefficients a and b in f(x)=a*Ta^4+b*Ts^4 cannot be derived from the coefficients A,B,C without more physical information as already pointed out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I shared a link with the complete data. I hope this is sufficient for you to answer the question properly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I took your data and did a 4th order polynomial fit.  Here's the result:

```
QL = -58.607 + x*(4.8336 + x*(-0.0772 + x*(-2e-5 + x*8e-5)))

R^ = 0.9999

x = (Ta - Ts)
```

If you want the equation to be in terms of Ta and Ts instead of the difference you should substitute and do the algebra.

Comment: OK. Of course one can have a good fitting with a polynomial function of sufficient large order. But the values found for the coefficients of the polynomial have no physical signifiance and are not consistent with the coefficients of the radiation law.

Comment: Agreed, because the fitting equation is not of the same form as the radiation law.  Like I said, I'd do the algebra and rearrange to get it into that form.  You'll have a term (Ta^4 -Ts^4) and a bunch of other terms that don't appear in the radiation law.  Those will tell you something about how your data/fit deviate from the physics.  It's your question, data, and fit.   You asked how to fit - I did it.

Comment: @JJacquelin thank you for your helpful comments. Is it possible to derive an equation that does have a physical significance by using the complete sheet of data that I have uploaded? I'd prefer that over a polynomial fit. Thanks

Comment: Possible?  Maybe.  That's your job, isn't it?  Perhaps you need more independent variables: Ta, Ts, Lin, and Lout.

Comment: @Yoni Verhaegen. Using the big data joint to your question the regression for coefficients a and b to fit the equation LNET=a*(TA+273.15)**4-b*(TS+273.15)**4 the result is a=0.00000004536 and b=0.000000055 which are exactly the values that you used to compute the data LNET. Thus you didn't give an experimental data for QL but you give a computed data using "supposed" coefficients 0.8 and 0.97 ,. The data doesn't give more information and so is not usable. This is a vicious circle. To obtain pertinent answer you should rewrite differently your question to make clear what you are looking for.